# Google Sheets Stopwatch With a Start and Stop Button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a total beginner in Google Apps Script and Java but I need a stopwatch in Google Sheets with a start and stop function. Ideally the button should be a toggle button so I can start and stop the stopwatch with only one single button. And the time should be displayed. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite what you want but here's a quick 2 button method:

```
function startTimer() {
  stopwatch('start');
}
function stopTimer() {
  stopwatch('stop');
}
function stopwatch(mode) {
  if (mode == 'start') {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D8').setValue(start);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D7').setValue('Running...');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Stopwatch running...');
  }

  if (mode == 'stop') {
    var start =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D8').getValue();
    if (!start) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D7').setValue('Not Started');
    }
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsed = (end - start) / 1000;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D7').setValue(elapsed);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Stopwatch off.');
  }
}
```

[image]

Google `google sheets create button` to find out how to create the 2 buttons, then assign each to the start and stop functions.

If you really want one button, read up on how to modify the button (drawing) methods between function calls here:
[Ref - Drawing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very very much, you helped me a lot :)